# --auth-dry-run in AWS cli missing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I'm dealing with the behemoth that is the AWS IAM permissions system.

There are so many options that it can be extremely difficult to pinpoint which permissions are missing/too restrictive. The documentation in

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policy-structure.html#check-required-permissions

describes a seemingly-useful flag that can be added to cli commands. Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to work. Am I missing something?

```
aws --version
aws-cli/1.11.47 Python/2.7.12 Linux/3.4.0+ botocore/1.5.10
```

Answer (score 4):

The new AWS CLI `ec2` command supports a `--dry-run` option for all EC2 operations.  This is actually provided by the EC2 service and it will check to see if the credentials provided have the permission to perform the requested operation.  It sounds like that will do what you are asking for.

```
aws ec2 run-instances <...> --dry-run
```

Comment: But they don't provide the DecodeAuthorizationMessage message. Is this available elsewhere?

Comment: The ``DecodeAuthorizationMessage`` request is part of the STS service.  In boto3 you could create a client like ``sts = boto3.client('sts')`` and then call ``sts.decode_authorization_message(<...>)``.

Comment: Or for the AWSCLI, just use ``aws sts decode-authorization-message <...>``

Comment: Good info, I was aware of `--dry-run` but didn't realize it always performed a permission check.

Comment: But where do I get the message to begin with? It is supposed to be returned by --auth-dry-run but is not returned by --dry-run.

Answer (score 2):

That's from the old ec2 command line tool. I don't think the new unified AWS CLI tool has an auth-dry-run option.

Comment: Is there a work around? At re:Invent I saw a pm use the DecodeAuthorizationMessage feature. It seams like something I would really want to make use of.